# Unable to create Kubernetes Cluster in GCP

Tags: kubernetes

Over the last few hours, I have  been trying to create a Kubernetes cluster in GCP. But could not successfully create. The error says "Unable to create the cluser". For sometime, I tried using the web cobsole and later switched to using gcloud. But nothing worked.

Can someone help me here? What is the mistake I am committing.

Regards
Raj

Answer (score 1):

There was an outage: https://status.cloud.google.com/incidents/sqeWSRmcrJZyE2zSrJ74

It should be now resolved for most users. If you are still having troubles it's recommended to get in touch with support team.